# Performace issues while using hibernate 'Restrictions.in'

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have a table in Oracle:  UserDetail[id, name, country]. The problem statement is to  get all 'UserDetail' entities whose 'name' is from a list of given input list using Hibernate. The most obvious solution is using 'Restrictions.in' from hibernate criteria api:

```
//Session Construction code
List<String> usernames = getUserNames();   
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserDetail.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("name", usernames)); //usernames -> List of usernames 
List<UserDetail> users = criteria.list();
```

The question is will there be any performance issues if the size of list(usernames) is like 10k and the number of users present in the database is roughly around 10 million. Would like to know what the performance issue will be and what can be an alternative way to get the data set with this kind of filter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The best way to find out would probably be to try out. I guess that this should not be a problem, provided that the 'name' column is properly indexed

Answer (score 0):

If this list of user names is determined through some kind of query, I would recommend you embed that query as subquery instead as that will usually perform better. If the list is provided by a user, there is not much you can do other than what you already have.